# Extract Specific data from Large CSV Dump file

Tags: excel, csv, logic, data-extraction

i have large data of more then 1 million entries in CSV format contain the user information from my company. I have used Recsv Editor to remove the extra columns from the file. Now i have following columns

```
ID    NAME    EMAIL        SUB_STATUS   SUB_DATE      SMS_RECEIVED  MEMBER
1     John    abc@abc.com  true         01.01.2018    true          true
2     David   abc@abc.com  false        01.01.2018    true          true
3     Raza    abc@abc.com  true         01.01.2018    true          false
4     Syed    abc@abc.com  false        01.01.2018    false         false
5     Eidi    abc@abc.com  true         01.01.2018    false         false
```

I have more than 1 million records but i need to extract the data from it based on specific conditions for example here is example logic

```
Extract all users which SUB_STATUS=true and SMS_RECEIVED=false and MEMBER=true OR
SUB_STATUS=false and SMS_RECEIVED=false and MEMBER=false
```

And i can then get the output on csv based on above example conditions.

How can I archive this? I am windows user, tried PowerShell, Recsveditior. File is too big cannot open on excel.

Comment: Have you considered using a database?

Comment: Sample condition is an appropriate for SQL language. Do you have access to a database like Oracle? or what other programming language do you know?

Comment: I have phpmyadmin but cannot import this large file! other option i have is ReCSVeditor and not sure what else i have option!

Comment: Use MS Query; set it up to do CSV imports and use that to filter the data before import

Comment: problem is i cannot open file in Excel, it crashes due to above 1 million records

Comment: To whom are you responding with your statement about not be able to open in Excel?  None of the suggestions made in the comments would seem to require that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue to import this big file to Excel, just you will need to split the data. Once that you split that one, you can apply filters.

The problem is just the time it takes. I use this macro for a 50 million lines CSV file and it works. Just take time to copy. Separator was ",", check your separator.

```
Sub ReadCSVFiles()

Dim i, j, k, l, m As Long
Dim UserFileName As String
Dim strTextLine As String
Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile
Dim Word() As String

UserFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename
Open UserFileName For Input As #iFile
i = 1
j = 1
Check = False

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, strTextLine
    If i >= 1048576 Then
        i = 1
        j = j + 1
    Else
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, j) = strTextLine
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop
Close #iFile

Worksheets.Add
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
ws1Col = ws1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
ws1Row = ws1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
k = 0
l = 0
Dim Items(1 To 16384) As Integer

For i = 1 To ws1Col
    For j = 1 To ws1Row
        Length = UBound(Split(ws1.Cells(j, i).Value2, ",", , vbBinaryCompare))
        'Change the separator here
        If Length > k Then
            k = Length
        End If
        For m = 0 To k
            Word() = Split(ws1.Cells(j, i).Value2, ",", , vbBinaryCompare)
            ws2.Cells(j, i + l + m).Value2 = Word(m)
        'Change the separator here
        Next
    Next
    If i = 1 Then
        Items(i) = k
    Else
        Items(i) = k + Items(i - 1)
    End If
    k = 0
    l = Items(i)
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try **q**. This tool allows you to run SQL queries direcly on CSV, to extract subsets of your data: https://harelba.github.io/q/

You could also give Excel **PowerPivot** a try, or MS Access!!